Errors in Databricks query history for SQL Warehouse Classic cluster
Issue Summary:
Experiencing problems when transferring data from Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) to Databricks Delta Lake tables using Qlik Replicate.
Source: Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI)
Destination: Databricks Delta Lake tables
Problem Statement:
Data duplicacy
Missing data
Details:
Logs from Qlik Replicate point to issues in Databricks.
Logs from Databricks, checked via "Query History," also show issues.
Unable to diagnose the exact errors causing data duplication and missing data.
Some network-related errors have been identified.
Uncertain about the next steps to mitigate the problem.
Sample error at Databricks side:
Error 1:
Query could not be scheduled: HTTP Response code: 500
Error 2:
[DELTA_CONCURRENT_APPEND] ConcurrentAppendException: Files were added to the root of the table by a concurrent update. Please try the operation again.
Conflicting commit: {"timestamp":1722250928325,"userId":"5954939804701401","userName":"aaaaaaa@xyz.com","operation":"MERGE","operationParameters":{"predicate":["((ITEM#22092922 = seg1_repcol#22092878) AND (LOC#22092925 = seg2_repcol#22092879))"],"matchedPredicates":[{"actionType":"update"}],"statsOnLoad":false,"notMatchedBySourcePredicates":[],"notMatchedPredicates":[]},"readVersion":2917,"isolationLevel":"WriteSerializable","isBlindAppend":false,"operationMetrics":{"numTargetRowsCopied":"0","numTargetRowsDeleted":"0","numTargetFilesAdded":"1","numTargetBytesAdded":"1282377","numTargetBytesRemoved":"1005294","numTargetDeletionVectorsAdded":"158","numTargetRowsMatchedUpdated":"28916","executionTimeMs":"209330","numTargetRowsInserted":"0","numTargetRowsMatchedDeleted":"0","numTargetDeletionVectorsUpdated":"158","scanTimeMs":"83197","numTargetRowsUpdated":"28916","numOutputRows":"28916","numTargetDeletionVectorsRemoved":"158","numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceUpdated":"0","numTargetChangeFilesAdded":"0","numSourceRows":"29161","numTargetFilesRemoved":"1","numTargetRowsNotMatchedBySourceDeleted":"0","rewriteTimeMs":"84773"},"tags":{"noRowsCopied":"true","delta.rowTracking.preserved":"false","restoresDeletedRows":"false"},"engineInfo":"Databricks-Runtime/15.2.x-photon-scala2.12","txnId":"eb912069-75fd-4f33-9829-a9cb191b4b7e"}
Sample error at Qlik side pointing to Databricks:
Error1:
02728323: 2024-07-11T00:50:57 [TARGET_LOAD     ]E:  RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 08S01 NativeError: 124 Message: [Simba][Hardy] (124) A 503 response was returned but no Retry-After header was provided. Original error: Unknown [1022502]  (ar_odbc_stmt.c:5090)
Error 2:
02602439: 2024-07-28T18:12:49 [TARGET_APPLY    ]T:  RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 08S01 NativeError: 115 Message: [Simba][Hardy] (115) Connection failed with error: SSL_read: Connection reset by peer [1022502]  (ar_odbc_stmt.c:4737)
02602439: 2024-07-28T18:12:49 [TARGET_APPLY    ]T:  Network error encountered  (ar_odbc_util.c:1242)
Error 3:
04171826: 2024-07-29T14:43:45 [TARGET_APPLY    ]T:  Failed (retcode -1) to execute statement

Provide the query you are using here.

@JayashankarGS - we are getting errors which INSERT / DELETE & MERGE statements. these statements are generated by QLIKReplicate itself.

Is there any partitions in your table. Please provide the schema of details of your table.

No partitions, Just a managed table. so Qlik replicate dumps the data to delta lake table in databricks. We get the data merged/updated. Hope I am able to explain.


This exception occurs when a concurrent operation adds files in the same partition (or anywhere in an unpartitioned table) that your operation reads. The file additions can be caused by INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE operations.

You can refer here about that exception.
Since, you haven't done any partition the cause of error is addition of files by INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE operations in an unpartitioned table.
So, the possible solution is

Setting the isolation level to WriteSerializable which does not conflict with blind insert operation.
Creating partition on column you used for condition.
Using Row-level concurrency.

So, try update these changes in your table.

Thank you for the response. Looking at the details and the link provided, it seems we can do the changes in Delta Live tables. What we are trying to do is - sending the data to Databricks DELTA Lake tables directly (without writing any merge/insert statements) using Qlik Replicate. So, all these are handled internally within ADB. Please correct me if i have incorrect understanding on your response.

What is the type of cluster you are using? All-purpose or SQL Warehouse? If you are on Databricks runtime 14.1 on a an all-purpose cluster, then it is not supported with Qlik Replicate.
Check the compatibility matrix in the documentation for your version of qlik replicate to see if your LTS version is supported with your current Qlik Replicate version.
Compatibility matrix here
